# UWP: Web credentials cannot be backup

Tags: .net, windows, uwp, credential-manager

We are developping a application using UWP, we have sensible data that we have stored using `PasswordVault`. Regarding this step, no issue. This morning we realise that an administrator can export a backup to restore its credential locker.

To POC this step, we tried it, but looks like the `Web credentials` from the UWP are not exported. There is a reason of that ?

`cmdkey.exe /list`

Does not list the credentials, it is link to a specific condition link to the domain ?

Comment: Please provide specific steps to reproduce the problem and how do you store web credentials in UWP? What behavior you expect？

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT We have a UWP application, we use PasswordVault to create, read, delete password inside the credential locker. These password are stored into the web credentials;

When we try to export for a backup the data from the credential manager, these data are not present. We expect to see them

Comment: I'd suggest you submit a feedback request about this API  `Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault.Add(PasswordCredential)` in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**-> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.